# MySQL: Reassigning/resorting numeric fields in large dataset

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with the following structure:

```
event_id      event_name         event_pic     event_sort
1             event1              ev1.jpg       1
2             event2              ev2.jpg       2
3             event3              ev3.jpg       3
4             event4              ev4.jpg       4
5             event5              ev5.jpg       5
6             event6              ev6.jpg       6
7             event7              ev7.jpg       7
```

The user is provided an option to rearrange the events. He can rearrange multiple events in single shot. Suppose he selects event1, event2 and moves it after say event 5.

The logical recordset will now look like:

```
event_id      event_name         event_pic     event_sort
3             event3              ev3.jpg       3
4             event4              ev4.jpg       4
5             event5              ev5.jpg       5
1             event1              ev1.jpg       1 <--- moved from top
2             event2              ev2.jpg       2 <--- moved from top
6             event6              ev6.jpg       6
7             event7              ev7.jpg       7
```

Tthe actual data set will run into thousands of records, and the selection rows(event1, event2 here) would be hundreds of rows.

I believe that basically I do not need to physically move the record order, instead I need to only update the `event_sort` field. So that that the table will look like:

```
event_id      event_name         event_pic     event_sort
    1             event1              ev1.jpg       6  <-- updated
    2             event2              ev2.jpg       7  <-- updated
    3             event3              ev3.jpg       3
    4             event4              ev4.jpg       4
    5             event5              ev5.jpg       5
    6             event6              ev6.jpg       8  <-- updated
    7             event7              ev7.jpg       9  <-- updated
```

The problem is that the rows will be moved around multiple times. And I do not think the above way would work either.

I believe that I need to reassign the `event_sort` values for ALL the records every time a sort takes place, but I am worried that with a huge dataset this will be very slow.

I would appreciate if any MySQL gurus can give me some tips on how to handle this problem. I am not an expert in the more advanced features of MySQL.

Comment: Most of that rearranging should probably be handled in code, and only applied when the user does a final ok/confirm of the changes. You can simply preserve the original ordering information to only update those that have actually changed.

Comment: @Uueerdo: The problem is that the user can confirm a change, then make more changes and confirm it again and so on.I am not sure how to apply a MySQL update statement for above situation...

Comment: There should be no problem with that; on every confirmation, reload the information so the last confirmed values become the new "original" ones.